# If ActionScript is based on ECMAScript, why does it have classes and looks almost the same as Java?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

In [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActionScript), it says that ActionScript 3.0 conforms to ECMA 4th edition.  But instead of looking like JavaScript and having no class or extend, ActionScript 3.0 code looks like Java and have the `class` statement and even have `extend`?

Answer (score 7):

Actionscript 3 was designed while the ECMA 4 spec was still under development. It's divergent; it conforms to ECMA 4 but goes beyond it.

Answer (score 4):

Because the ECMAScript 4th Edition draft that ActionScript 3 is based on had `class` and `extends` and so on.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#ECMAScript.2C_4th_Edition

http://www.ecma-international.org/activities/Languages/Language%20overview.pdf

Later, the 4th Edition draft was replaced by ECMAScript Harmony:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#History_2

Some would say that the reason for this was [business politics](http://whydoeseverythingsuck.com/2008/08/ru-roh-adobe-screwed-by-ecmascript.html), but you would have to form your own informed opinion on that.

Answer (score 3):

Actionscript  was compliant with ECMA from the very start.

You could imagine javascript & actionscript as a fork from a single standard ie ECMA, With Javascript inclined to add power to browsers while Actionscript geared towards flash development.

Seems fair since every company at one time was in a bid to create own version. For eg, Consider the [Microsoft's version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript) of ECMA.

You might also consider from the very link you shared that :

> In response to user demand for a language better equipped for larger
>   and more complex applications, ActionScript 2.0 featured compile-time
>   type checking and class-based syntax, such as the keywords class and
>   extends.

So you could see that most of the changes were really user driven, rather than a co-incidental similarity.

Answer (score 0):

In general, to be standard compliant does not mean that only the features defined by the standard have to be available. You can implement a standard to be compliant but you can also implement additional functionality.

You can treat ECMA Script as a kind of subset that defines the basic language structure, syntax and semantics. Then ECMA is only a subset of ActionScript. The language adds a wide range of features to this subset.

Another example could be MySQL. It implements the SQL standard but provides much more functionality like the standard would do.